# How can i know if the function in my DLL is called from azure function or simple web application

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-triggers

So i have a web application with a DLL having function lets say function add().

I am writing an azure function V1 that has the reference of my DLL.

So is there a way for me to identify whether the function add() in my DLL is called  from azure function

or it is called from my web application.

Comment: Send it a value? `myProperty(boolean calledFromAzure)`?

Comment: @Liam adding a parameter will have a huge impact as the application is old.
can i use environment variables in that dll? will it be accessible?

Comment: You could set an environment variable or similar when running it as a web-app, and just check that.

What are you trying to achieve though?

Comment: @RB. actually i wan to give different connection strings when it is called from webapp and azure function.

Comment: Put your connection string in the web.config and just deploy a different one to each environment.

Comment: ??? Surely the connection string is part of the configuration that you apply to your instance *before* you call the method on the instance?

Comment: @RB. the function which i will call actually  calls another function which get the required connection string as i have multiple database servers.
for azure it will be of sql managed instance and for web app it will be simple DB.

Comment: So your real issue here is that your hard coding your connection strings, yeah, stop doing that...

Comment: @RB.its not hardcoding.i am getting the value of connection string from config file in webapp.and i want to know if i can identify that if this function is called from azure i can use the azure app environment variable to assign it diff connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [Caller Info attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information)

> By using Caller Info attributes, you can obtain information about the
>   caller to a method. You can obtain file path of the source code, the
>   line number in the source code, and the member name of the caller.
>   This information is helpful for tracing, debugging, and creating
>   diagnostic tools.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this tomorrow and will let you know.